# What's instagram's query_hash's algorithm?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I find them to be different for each action and also different from session to session. So I am assuming it must be relevant to some particular information within the session. Looks like all the available projects related to this matter on GitHub simply copied and pasted author's `query_hash` instead of generating them.

Comment: Hey man, did you get answer to this?